# Loading All Eloquent Models into a DI Container

Tags: php, design-patterns

So i realize that this is possibly the worst idea I've ever had, but I'm incredibly curious as to whether or not it fits into an Anti-Pattern and should be avoided, or is a perfectly acceptable solution.

In my test case I'll be using Eloquent and Pimple, however i do not believe they are relevant, as long as you have a DI Container and a ORM which uses a Model-like class. I'm also using PSR 4 Naming to make assumptions about the file structure.

The primary objective of this exercise is to automatically add all Models to your DI Container, without actually including and creating an instance of the class, so that you can be lazy and not manually define it in your DI Container.

The example code that i'm providing below skips some fine tooth checking such as ensuring that there is a parameter-less constructor, ensuring it's not already defined in the container, etc, etc

```
$container = new Container(); // DI Container
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path/to/models");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $class) {
    if ($class->isFile() && $class->getExtensions() == "php") {
        $filename = $class->getBasename(".php");
        $container[$filename] = function() use ($class, $filename) {
            $classname = "\\Fully\\Qualified\\Namespace\\{$filename}";
            require_once $class;
            return new $classname();
        }        
    }
}
```

So the real question here essentially is, is there any Anti-Patterns in the above code, and are there any real security issues to worry about using it in practice if there isn't an Anti-Pattern that this fits into.

Answer (score 1):

No, I believe this is basically how a lot of DI libraries work (in java-land)

However java/etc would read the libraries in once and store them in memory... PHP would require you to re-read from the directory each time like this... So I think its appropriate.

The only security issue would be allowing others to write(over-write) your DI classes. So if you protect those... I 'think' you should be fine...

( "Think" because I haven't done PHP in years, and haven't kept up with best SOP for security there )

Comment: One of the goals of this solution was to ensure the files are only read from within the closure, meaning that you would need to call `$container->get("UserModel")` before it loaded the contents of UserModel.php, presumably using something like Super Closure, you could cache the Closures to disk / memory, improving performance...